# Prevent loading from cache for a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, caching

When I load the page for first time, I'm getting 200 status code and the page is loading file. The problem is from second time getting 304 status and the page is not working. How to set the cache control off for the particular JSON file in my JS file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);

app.controller("deviceCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $http,$timeout)      {    

var planReq = $http.get("data/callplans.json").then(function (response1) {
  $scope.callplanList = response1.data;
  return response1;
});

});
```

Comment: `data/callplans.json?rnd='+new Date().getTime()`

Comment: pass the config cache value as true as the second param of $http.get(url, {
cache: false
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..:

```js
var planReq = $http.get("data/callplans.json?r=" + Math.random() ).then(function (response1) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me try this and get back to you.